# Clone Production RDS Database for Load Test Purporse

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am planning to execute some stress and load test on a RDS Database.

I have a AWS production account with a PostgreSQL RDS Instance and 
I would like to clone a specific database and copy to a PostgreSQL in a AWS Development account. I am planning to run this process weekly or daily.

What is the best way?

1. Take a snapshot from Production Database and restore it on Development account.
2. Make a pg_dump, create a VPC Peering and then use a pg_restore

Any suggestions?